# Thymeleaf and using LocalDate class with methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Hi I have a SpringBoot application which has a Timesheet class, which has a LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(); declaration. I have a ThymeLeaf page which has the three declarations like this:

```
<span th:if="${timesheet.id == 0} AND ${#temporals.format(timesheet.localDate.now(), 'dd-MM-yyyy')}" class="missing">MISSING</span>
    <span th:unless="${timesheet.id == 0}" class="draft">DRAFT</span></td>
    <span th:unless="${timesheet.id == 0}" AND "${#temporals.format(timesheet.date.plusDays(7}, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}" class="available">AVAILABLE</span></td>
    <span th:unless="${timesheet.id != 0}" AND "${#temporals.format(timesheet.date.minusDays(10), 'dd-MM-yyyy')}" class="overdue">OVERDUE</span></td>
```

I am checking for that the timesheet.id == 0, then I want to display the date for certain conditions for instance, an Overdue timesheet, is when the timesheet.date is 10 days old. I'm using an AND clause to join the conditions, but I get a parsing error, which is in red, for Visual Studio Code, my question is how do I accomplish testing for the condition, and displaying the correct formatted date?

Thanks for your help

MindGames

Comment: It might be more suitable to perform decisions like "this book is overdue" in the controller/service layer, not the view layer.

Comment: You don't show us the error (you should do). Or try to run the code and show us the text of the complete stack trace.

Comment: Having said that, you have code like this in your Thymeleaf tempalte: `if (A and B)`. Both expressions `A` and `B` need to evaluate to a boolean result (`true` or `false`) for the overall `if` to also evaluate to `true` or `false`. But you have `${timesheet.id == 0}` - which is a boolean expression, but you also have `${#temporals.format(...)}"` which does _not_ evaluate to true or false. It evaluates to a string. See the [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless) for examples. The same applies to `th:unless` also.